# Erro ao instalar Java na máquina virtual

Tags: java, vagrant

Estou tentando rodar uma playbook (*ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini arquivo.yml*) que instala o java na minha maquina virtual,mas ele acusa erro na task de instalação:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "apt-key add -", "failed": true,
>   "msg": "gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.", "rc": 2, "stderr": "gpg:
>   no valid OpenPGP data found.\n", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

O arquivo .yml correspondente a esta task está assim:

```
 name: Add the webupd8 APT repository key
  tags:
    - java
    - java-webupd8
  apt_key: data="{{ lookup('file', 'webupd8.key.asc') }}" state=present
  # Use a static file because right now using just an ID fails

- name: Add the webupd8 APT repository
  tags:
    - java
    - java-webupd8
  apt_repository: repo="deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu precise main" state=present
```

Bom pelo o que o erro acuso eu imagino que eu esteja pondo o valor errado na variável **apt_key** ,porém não faço ideia do que devo por no lugar do está ali.

PS:Sou newbie no provisionamento de maquinas virtuais e afins.